# Javascript checking for Power of 2

Tags: javascript, html

I am new with Javascript, I need help with a function. I have created this program: https://codepen.io/aareval4/pen/dyYyoLp . Instead of inserting manually the numbers of the value of a power of 2,

For example:  if( countblack == 1 ||countblack == 5 ||countblack == 13)

What I would like to do is creating a formula that checks if total count is a power of 2 so it can add as a total point.

any help is much appreciated.

```
    var count = 0;
    var countblack = 0;
    var countred = 0;
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

    black.onclick = function () {

      if (countblack == 1 ||countblack == 5 ||countblack == 13 ||countblack == 29 ||countblack == 61 ||countblack == 125){
      ++count;
      displayCount.innerHTML = count; 
      countblack++;
      displayCountblack.innerHTML = countblack;
      a++;
      displayCountblackReinforcer.innerHTML = a;

      }
      else {
        countblack++;
        displayCountblack.innerHTML = countblack;
      }

};

red.onclick = function () {
  count++;
  countred++;
  b++;
  displayCount.innerHTML = count;
  displayCountred.innerHTML = countred;
  displayCountredReinforcer.innerHTML = b;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Make an array and a number that starts at 1, then iterate from 2 to however many iterations you need. On each iteration, add `2 ** i` to the number, then push the number to the array:

```js
const arr = [1];
let num = 1;
for (let i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
  num += 2 ** i;
  arr.push(num);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Then you can replace

```
if (countblack == 1 ||countblack == 5 ||countblack == 13 ||countblack == 29 ||countblack == 61 ||countblack == 125){
```

with

```
if (arr.includes(countblack)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient way:

Let's leverage the fact the power of two will have all "0" and single "1".

Example:

```
Decimal |   Binary
2       |   10
4       |   100
8       |   1000
16      |   10000
```

```js
// this check
if (countblack == 1 ||countblack == 5 ||countblack == 13 ||countblack == 29 ||countblack == 61 ||countblack == 125)
```

```js
// this can be used as a check
const isPowerOfTwo = (num) => {
  let binNum = (num).toString(2);
  let isValid = ((binNum.match(/1/g) || []).length === 1) && (binNum.length > 1);
  return isValid;
} 

// use the function like here 
console.log(isPowerTwo(16));
```

Note: `(binNum.length > 1)` this check is added because 1's binary also contains single 1.

Comment: "*1's binary also contains single 1.*" this is correct, two to the power of *zero* is indeed one. So, it's a valid power of two.